# How do I make this multithreading CAS program work properly?

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
class Foo {
public:
    std::atomic<int> flag = {0};
    int tmp[4] = {0,1,2,3};
    Foo() {}

    void first(function<void()> printFirst) {
        printFirst();
        flag.compare_exchange_weak(tmp[0], 1, std::memory_order_release);
    }

    void second(function<void()> printSecond) {
        while(!flag.compare_exchange_weak(tmp[1], 2, std::memory_order_acquire)) {}
        printSecond();
        while(!flag.compare_exchange_weak(tmp[2], 3, std::memory_order_release)) {}
    }

    void third(function<void()> printThird) {
        while(!flag.compare_exchange_weak(tmp[3], 4, memory_order_acquire)) { }
        printThird();
    }
};
```

This is an example from an interview question, I am not quite sure if I understand CAS correctly, here I wanted to let `printFirst(),printSecond() and printThird()` could be executed sequentially during multi thread environment.

But the result is not correct, can anyone help to explain what's going on here? e.g. I was expecting `while(!flag.compare_exchange_weak(tmp[1], 2, std::memory_order_acquire)) {}` wait busy wait until flag has been changed to `tmp[1]`, but it doesn't work that way actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flag.compare_exchange_weak(tmp[1], 2, std::memory_order_acquire)` stores the actual value of `flag` into `tmp[1]` if the comparison fails.

So, assuming `first` and `third` have not yet accessed `flag`, after one loop `tmp[1]` has value `0` and the next loop iteration will result in positive comparison, ending the loop.

You need to reset the first argument to `compare_exchange_weak` in each iteration.